# sed to remove leading comment on crontab with Sun Solaris 10

Tags: sed, cron, solaris

I am writing a sed command that should uncomment an entry in crontab on sun Solaris 10.

I have tried 2 ways and they are working on Ubuntu but they didn't work on Sun Solaris 10; it returns `sed: illegal option -- E` `crontab: can't open your crontab file.`

```
crontab -l | sed -E '/#* *([^ ]+  *){5}[^ ]*run_all.sh/s/^#* *//' | crontab -
```

also :

```
crontab -l | sed '/#* *\([^ ][^ ]*  *\)\{5\}[^ ]*run_all.sh\.sh/s/^#* *//' | crontab -
```

shell on crontab looks like :

```
###15 00 * * * /bill/u01/WORK/ALARMS/run_all.sh > /bill/u01/WORK/ALARMS/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`_RUN_ALL_PROCEDURE.log
```

Comment: Do you really need anything more complicated than `'/run_all\.sh/ s/^##* *//'`? in particular, I don't see any value in using capture groups within the address pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't overcomplicate the regex. 
To remove any possible hashtags at the beginning of lines containing the string `run_all.sh`, you could do:

```
crontab -l | sed 's/^#*\(.*run_all\.sh\)/\1/' | crontab -
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a Solaris system at hand to test it.

Comment: thank you dear you helped me alot, what if want to lead run_all.sh with ###shell what should i change?

Comment: You mean the reverse operation? Use `'s/.*run_all\.sh/###&/'` instead. The `&` is a shorthand for the matched regex in the replacement.